# Is the Cyber Buster effective against aircraft and tanks?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I'm contemplating a change to my weapon loadout in Saints Row 3.  I have access to the "Cyber Blaster" now, which is a weapon you use during one of the Decker missions.  So far I've kept the RC Possessor in this slot, and the Annihilator in the explosive weapon slot.

I'd want to replace the Annihilator with Satchel Charges, and the RC Possessor with the Cyber Buster, but I'm not certain if the Cyber Buster is capable as an anti-aircraft weapon.  The Annihilator locks on, and can take down most VTOLs/choppers with one hit, which makes this sort of thing a breeze.

If I take the Cyber Buster and the Satchel Charges, will I be at a disadvantage against aircraft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Saints Row Wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Cyber_Buster) says that a single fully-charged Cyber Buster shot will kill aircraft instantly. So, no, you'll be fine.

EDIT: I've since used the weapon myself. Basically, fully-charged shots instantly kill all occupants of any vehicle it hits. In the case of helicopters, this leaves it with nobody to keep it from spinning about and smacking into buildings.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?  Can you link to the wiki page where you read that?

Comment: Here's a link to the wiki page http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Cyber_Buster